# How do I periodically import from a source?

Tags: feeds

In the basic settings of a feeds importer there is a select list:

> Periodic import
>
> Every 30 min
>
> Choose how often a source should be imported periodically. Requires cron to be configured.

Merely selecting an option doesn't appear to import from my source every 30 minutes. It appears that I have to configure cron too. I've found a lot to read about this, but nothing that describes the basics.

What do I need to do to ensure my source is imported periodically? I can do a manual import without problem.

Answer (score 1):

For periodic import of feed, you have to configure cron.

Let say you want to import feed in every 1 hour then configure cron to run after every 1 hour too.

In Drupal 7 you can enable cron via the Administration > Configuration > System > Cron **(admin/config/system/cron)**.

For more information cron setup visit [here](https://drupal.org/cron)

Comment: My cron is set to run every 3 hours. After 3 hours elapses cron says it has run, but my content doesn't appear updated. If I run cron manually, it does update. Why isn't it updating automatically?

Comment: Have you check error log or system log etc. ?